# Instagram Valid Redirect URIs throwing validation error

Tags: html, validation, http, post, http-post

I'm trying to add a Valid Redirect URI to Instagram in the format of:-

```
 "ig" + "your clientId" + "://authorize"
```

E.g:- ig123456://authorize

What happens, however, is that Instagram throws the error of:

> You must enter an absolute URI that starts with 'http://' or 'https://'

I'm fairly certain this is a bug on instagram's end, as even creating a support request throws validation errors on that form too.

Can anyone help me verify this?

Comment: You should use the complete URL from http:

Comment: This is for a mobile app. The web URI contains the entire https://

Comment: Brother, Mobile app is also accessing information from the internet, you need to provide the complete address

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the complete web address starting from "https://" inorder for your mobile application to access the information from the internet.